# Pasar un calculo en ViewModel a un Servicio con MVVM C#

Tags: c#, mvvm

Tengo el `MainViewModel` (dentro de la carpeta ViewModel) el cual tiene este código:

```
    private double _numeroIntroducido;
    private double _resultado10p;
    private double _resultado20p;

    public double NumeroIntroducido
    {
        get => _numeroIntroducido;
        set
        {
            _numeroIntroducido = value;
            Resultado10p = (NumeroIntroducido * 10)/100;
            Resultado20p = (NumeroIntroducido * 20)/100;
            RaiseProperty();
        }
    }
    public double Resultado10p 
    {
        get => _resultado10p;
        set 
        {
            _resultado10p = value;
            RaiseProperty();          
        } 
    }

    public double Resultado20p 
    {
        get => _resultado20p;
        set 
        {
            _resultado20p = value;
            RaiseProperty();        
        }
    }
```

La idea es que el usuario introduzca por un `textBox` un numero, y debajo aparezca ese mismo numero con el 10% y 20% hecho. Hasta aquí todo bien, funciona.

Ahora me han pedido que el calculo que estoy realizando en el `MainViewModel`, lo pase a un Servicio. Estoy empezando hace poco con el tema de MVVM, y no se muy bien como pasar ese calculo a otra clase, e incorporarlo al proyecto en si.

¿Alguna ayuda? Si necesitáis alguna información mas, edito.

Comment: Cual es el concepto que tienes por servicio ? o sea es un class o es un servicio web, o webapi. Si es un class donde piensas definirlo? en un proyecto class library o alli mismo en en proyecto wpf

Comment: En principio seria una class dentro de la carpeta Service.

Comment: No me queda clara tu respuesta a la pregunta de Leandro Tuttini. De todos modos por si te sirve de orientación, si es una llamada a un servicio web o wcf por ejemplo, podrías llamar a través de un command, Si es a otro proyecto de la misma solución, podrías lanzar un evento a través del IEventAggregator del prism, que permite a publicadores y suscriptores comunicarse a través de eventos. Si editas tu pregunta y nos das más información seguro que podemos ayudarte.